# SwiftUI IPadOS app change text based on orientation

Tags: text, swiftui, device-orientation

I'd like to change Text displayed based on device orientation. A visual will describe what I am trying to achieve better :)

Here is landscape mode [image: landscape mode]
And here is portrait mode [image: portrait mode]

I'd like to display a short format for the month name in portrait mode and have found various posts describing how to achieve this by detecting device orientation. I also found that this is not in the best practice category so wondering if there is a better way.
Code is just a VStack with two Text components inside a ScrollView.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SwiftUI doesn't seem to have constraints, or constraint variants like the interface builder does for orientation. I don't think there is an established best practices for it yet.  I wouldn't hesitate to use the orientation values until something comes out that allow us to better react to orientation changes.

I would probably do something like this to react to orientation:

[Updated with @kevin-renskers improvement]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(orientation.isLandscape ? "Landscape" : "Portrait")
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.Publisher(center: .default, name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
          self.orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I like this, it's less code than other similar solutions I've seen :)

Comment: One problem with this solution is that you'll get notifications for all orientation changes, including ones your app might not support. Including `.portraitUpsideDown`, `.faceUp`, and `.faceDown`. So you'd want to add some code to only set the `orientation` @State variable if the new orientation is one of the ones you support, and also only set the initial `orientation` to a supported one.

Answer (score 9):

I would change the accepted answer a little bit to instead use `.onReceive`:

```swift
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.Publisher(center: .default, name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
  self.orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
}
```

This should handle unsubscribing automatically.

Comment: I think this solution is more modern and better with SwiftUI than the accepted answer. Nice!

Comment: I agree, this is better

Comment: This is the most SwiftUI based approach. However it didn't work for me until I put a call to  UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()  in my SwiftUI App as a call in the initialiser.

Comment: The issue with this solution and others that I've found is that UIDevice.current.orientation can be a lot more things than .portrait and .landscape(left or right). I keep running into issues where my iPad in a keyboard folio is registering as unknown or faceup. I've tried using other methods when this notification is received to compare UIScreen.main.bounds.height < UIScreen.main.bounds.width but these values don't always seem to update either. Still looking for a solution that consistently works.

Comment: UPDATE: After additional testing, I'm using the notification above but this bool
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation.isLandscape 
for a reliable way to detect if the device is in landscape mode and update the UI immediately.